# How can i send an object as a parameter in Swagger Documentation

Tags: swagger, documentation, lumen

i'm using Swagger to document my Lumen API and im using annotations. The thing is, i don't know how to achieve the structure that you can see on the picture with annotations
[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to this and how to get the structure that i wanted:

```
@OA\RequestBody(
     *          @OA\JsonContent(
     *              type="object",
     *              @OA\Property(property="idNumber", type="string"),
     *              @OA\Property(property="ClientId", type="string"),
     *              @OA\Property(property="inspection", type="array",
     *                  @OA\Items(type="object", properties = {
     *                      @OA\Property(property="Color", type="string"),
     *                      @OA\Property(property="time", type="string"),
     *                      @OA\Property(property="place", type="string"),
     *                      @OA\Property(property="issue", type="string"),
     *                      @OA\Property(property="details", type="string"),
     *                  }),
     *              ),
     *              @OA\Property(property="detailId", type="string"),
     *              @OA\Property(property="WayPayment", type="array",
     *                  @OA\Items(type="object", properties = {
     *                      @OA\Property(property="banking", type="string"),
     *                      @OA\Property(property="numbercard", type="string"),
     *                      @OA\Property(property="numberpayment", type="string"),
     *                  }),
     *              ),
     *          ),
     *     ),
```